# How to skip an initializer only for worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some patches for Mongrel to run with Rails 2.3.8 in initializers. This does not work when I want to start a Deamon. When I remove the patch from initializers it works fine. What I am looking is to skip that particular initializer while starting the Deamon.

Thanks for your help in advance.